# android getCellLocation() vs getAllCellInfo()

Tags: android, cellid

I know Google suggests to use getAllCellInfo() to get all observed cell information from all radios and use getCellLocation() when previous function returns null. But here is my test:
When calling getCellLocation(), it will return me like this:
cellid:21077767;lac:14940;PHONE_TYPE_GSM

while calling getAllCellInfo(), it will return me like this(including the primary and neighboring cells):
cellid:25661;lac:367;CellInfoGsm
cellid:25773;lac:367;CellInfoGsm
cellid:25662;lac:367;CellInfoGsm

My question is why cellid and lac is totally different from these two functions return. Who can tell me which function gives me the correct cellid my phone is connecting. Thanks!

Comment: `and use getCellLocation() when previous function returns null. But here is my test:`. Well did it return null? No? Then you should not do this 'test'.